# Fragment y DialogFragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragment, alertdialog, dialog-fragment

estoy con un problema, necesito transmitir informacion desde mi dialogFragment a mi Fragment como lo hago?
Yo hice un diagolFragment que carga 2 valores en 2 editText, y necesito que esos valores los tome el fragment luego para tratarlos, y no importa donde llame al dialog simpre se compila todo el fragment antes de ejecutar el dialog, por lo que no me toma los datos, lo trate de hacer con un AlertDialog pero no genera los botones ya sea con la configuración sola del setPositiveButton, o haciéndolo manualmente con POSITIVE_BUTTON, ya no se como hacerlo porque no me toma los datos el fragment.
Esto es lo que tengo pero no hace lo que debe:

```
    binding.multiplicacion.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_menu_multiplicacion)
    binding.TituloDePagina.text = "Ingresa los factores a multiplicar"

    binding.Aceptar.setOnClickListener {
        var primerFactor = binding.setPrimerFactor.text.toString()
        var segundoFactor = binding.setSegundoFactor.text.toString()

        pasarFactoresAlFragment(primerFactor,segundoFactor)

        dialog?.dismiss()
    }
    return root
}

private fun pasarFactoresAlFragment(primerFactor: String, segundoFactor: String) {

    val fragmentMultiplicacion = MultiplicacionFragment()
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("Primer Factor", primerFactor)
    bundle.putString("Segundo Factor", segundoFactor)
    fragmentMultiplicacion.arguments = bundle

}
```

Comment: Bienvenid@, te sugerimos agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, agrega más información, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.